# Why isn't my apple id letting me download songs?

Tags: itunes

I pre-ordered an album, but I haven't been able to download the singles released because when I type in my apple ID it asks for verification, and every time I try to answer one of the verification questions it says I'm answering it wrong. I'm not though. I really need to download more songs because the album comes out tomorrow. What should I do?

Comment: When you say it asks for verification, is it asking you to confirm your billing information? In any case the best bet would be to call Apple's iTunes support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the email to get your password reset.

[Go to Apple ID website](https://appleid.apple.com/)

[Use email authentication](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5787)

> Select “Email authentication,” then select Next. Apple will send the
>   email to your primary or rescue email address.